# got error messages when installing Vpython and Matplotlib on Mac

Tags: python, matplotlib, vpython

I was trying to install vpython and matplotlib using

```
pip install vpython
```

but got

```
error: could not create '/library/python/2.7/site-
packages/vpnotebook':permission denied
```

and

```
pip install matplotlib
```

But what i got is

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-
packages/singledispatch_helpers.pyc'
```

both errors say "permission denied"

What should I do to solve this problem?

**update**: i just solved this problem by downloading anaconda. Thanks to @Paul H

Comment: Can you install other packages?

Comment: @DavidG, i only need to install numpy,matplotlib, and vpython. I got error messages when install them. The only thing that i have successfully installed is pip. For installation of numpy, it gives different error message so i will post another question about this later. just want this problem get solved first.

Comment: use anaconda on a mac.

Comment: @PaulH Thank you. it worked!!